# Merging two diff XMLS using XSLT(1.0)

Tags: xslt

I am new to XSLT and I need help in merging two different XML documents into one.

XML1.xml

```
<customers>
    <customer>
        <Person name="Ram" Id="101"/>
        <address>flat 4</address>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <Person name="Raghav" Id="102"/>
        <address>flat 9</address>
    </customer>
</customers>
```

XML2.xml

```
<Products>
    <Product>
        <name>Onida Tv</name>
        <consumer>Ram</consumer>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <name>washing machine</name>
        <consumer>Ram</consumer>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <name>Water purifier</name>
        <consumer>Raghav</consumer>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <name>iPhone</name>
        <consumer>Raghav</consumer>
    </Products>
</Products>
```

Desired XML output:

```
<customers>
    <customer>
        <Person name="Ram" Id="101"/>
        <address>flat 4</address>
        <products>
            <name>washing machine</name>
            <name>Onida TV</name>
        </products>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <Person name="Raghav" Id="102"/>
        <address>flat 9</address>
        <products>
            <name>iPhone</name>
            <name>Water purifier</name>
        </products>
    </customer>
</customers>
```

The second XML is to be considered external in this context. I need to append to each customer the corresponding products. How can I do that?

Comment: Please state XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. -- Note: `"Ram"` is not the same thing as `" Ram "`; are you sure that's how your data looks?

Comment: On second look, it can't be, because it's not well-formed. This `<name="Ram" Id="101">` is not XML.

Comment: But your XML2.xml is still not right....

Comment: @Kilazur I have rolled back your edit for one reason: the file name `XML2.xml` is essential to the question and it is used in my answer.

Comment: @michael Would have been easier to just edit the names :p

Comment: @Kilazur No, it wouldn't - I would have to check everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="lookup-document" select="document('XML2.xml')" />
<xsl:key name="product-by-consumer" match="Product" use="consumer" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="customer">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="name" select="Person/@name" />
        <products>
            <!--  switch context to the other document in order to use key -->
            <xsl:for-each select="$lookup-document">
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('product-by-consumer', $name)/name"/>
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </products>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes that customer names are unique.

Comment: Maybe you should offer a modification to the original XML, giving each product a consumer's ID (which is, I guess, truly unique) instead of a  consumer's name, and doing the transformation on this ID.

Comment: @Kilazur Maybe you should address this to the OP?